# How to get a 2d DataFrame from 1d Series data

Tags: python, pandas

How to get a 2d DataFrame from 1d Series data.

I have data x,

```
x=[1,2,3,....,99]
```

How can I get a 2d matrix DataFrame:

```
{[1,2,3,...,99],[1,2,3,...,99],[1,2,3,...,99]....[1,2,3,....,99]}
```

(the DataFrame is a 100 raws 50 columns matrix).

```
from pandas import DataFrame,Series
import numpy as np
x=Series(np.arange(1,100))
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x, 50).reshape(-1,50))`?

Comment: pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x, 50).values.reshape(99,50))   Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a list of lists directly into a dataframe.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

li =[list(range(10))]*5
df = DataFrame(li)
print (df)
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x, 50).values.reshape(99,50)) Thank you very much!